# Type of Any Function

Tags: typescript

What is the type of any type of function? For example:

```
var f = function(something) {return 1;};
f = function() {return 'fdsa';};
f = function(p1, p2, p3) {DoNothing()};
```

What is the one type that f should have to make this compile in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var f: Function = function(something) {return 1;};
f = function() {return 'fdsa';};
f = function(p1, p2, p3) {DoNothing()};
f = 4; // error
f(3); // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

in TS we should use 3 different variables, unless we want to declare `f` as `any` so this in JS:

```
var f1 = function(something) {return 1;};
var f2 = function() {return 'fdsa';};
var f3 = function(p1, p2, p3) {DoNothing()};
```

would in TS have type like these:

```
var f1 : (something:any) => number;
var f2 : () => string;                          
var f3 : (p1:any, p2:string, p3:number) => void;
```

And implemenation could be like this:

```
f1 = (something:any) => { return 1; };
f2 = () => { return 'fdsa'; };           
f3 = (p1:any, p2:string, p3:number) => { DoNothing(); };
```

Comment: Thanks Radim. Is there any way to have one type without resorting to `any`? I want just one variable `f`.

Comment: I would say, NO. We need different explicit types. because these functions do have different structure. Let's think about it as in C# or Java. What we are trying with `Typescript` is to avoid the `any` (like `object`). And we can do it only if the type is clearly defined... I.e. what we can do in JS we cannot do in TS (unless with any) ... does it help? Extend: at least we can use nullable params... so singature could be like `(p1?:any, p2?:string, p?3:number)` ... but still it is like in C# or Java...

Comment: Good points. I agree. However, I just want something a little better than `any`, but not quite the full parameter type checking.